# see if string is starting to match another string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of keywords in an array and when the user types one of them correctly, I run the pass() function. I check if what the user has typed after each key has been typed ( on key up ) is equal to anything in the array.

I do this by on each key up, use a for loop to iterate through the array and if it matches at item in the array, then run the pass function, but if it is longer or equal to in length and not equal to an item in the array and is the end of the array has been reached then run a fail function.

Here is my code:

```
var keywords = new Array('', 'help', 'search', 'clock', 'folio', 'pong', 'simon');
for(var i=0; i<=(keywords.length)-1; i++){
if($('#code').val()===keywords[i]){
    pass(i);
}
else if(($('#code').val().length>=keywords[i].length) && (i === (keywords.length)-1)){
    fail();
}
}
```

Now, the problem that I am encountering is premature fail() execution. When the user types one of the longer keywords, the moment it is longer than one of the shorter keywords fail is executed.

Also, for some research on typing 'help' and 'search' both pass and fail run ?

Anyway, what I am wondering is there is there a way to improve my code to better so what I am trying to do and properly work?

**Is it possible to check if what the user is typing is matching one of the keywords and if it looks like they are spelling one of they keywords then not fail(), but the moment they mess up and spell something that is equal to length, but not the keyword then fail().**

For example: sear would cause a fail in my previous code, but in what I am now trying to do it wouldn't until the user types something like searck.

Comment: why not use [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to only call `fail()` when the `for` loop is done and nothing matched.

I can't tell what you were trying to accomplish with the `else if` logic.  Here's a version that calls `fail()` only if there were no matches.  It also takes the `$('#code').val()` out of the `for` loop for efficiency sakeand breaks out of the `for` loop when it finds a match since there's no reason to continue.

```
var keywords = new Array('', 'help', 'search', 'clock', 'folio', 'pong', 'simon');
var val = $('#code').val();
var fullMatch = false, partialMatch = false;

for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
    if (val === keywords[i]) {
        fullMatch = true;
        pass(i);
        break;
    } else if (val && !partialMatch) {
        if (keywords[i].indexOf(val) === 0) {
           partialMatch = true;
        }
    } 
}
if (!fullMatch && !partialMatch) {
    fail();
}
```

Comment: oh, true and that is just after the closing bracket of the for loop.
Wait, but the won't fail() run regardless even if pass() is executed?

Comment: @IMUXIxD - you have to add some logic to make it work.  You can set a boolean value when you find a match and check that boolean after the `for` loop to see if there were any matches.

Comment: That was what I was thinking. A boolean that is set to true is pass is executed and then if that is false then run fail().

Comment: This helps, but doesn't in the partial match case. Let me try your new, updated code. one second.

Comment: @IMUXIxD - typo.  It's `fullMatch`.

Comment: @IMUXIxD - I didn't include the partial match case because it isn't clear from your question or your code what you're trying to do with a partial match that is different than no match.

Comment: The difference between partial match and no match is that no match causes fail() to execute definitely, partial match waits until it id definitely not a match, then it executes fail. sear is okay, but searck is not, in regards to trying to match search.

Comment: @IMUXIxD - OK, I added partial match logic.  In the case of a partial match, it will not call `fail()`, but a partial match won't prevent the finding of a full match.

Comment: is there supposed to be a closing bracket before the else if?